# Compiling Shrew on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, shrew, cmake

I'm trying to build [Shrew VPN](https://www.shrew.net/), [version 2.2.1](https://www.shrew.net/download/ike) on [Debian 7.1](http://debian.org/); however, I've run into a problem that I can't get by.

`README.TXT` says I need to use [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) to build the [Shrew](https://www.shrew.net/) client...

> The following options are recommended when running the cmake configuration
>      for linux platforms. Please see the OPTIONS section for more details.
>
> ```
> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DQTGUI=YES -DETCDIR=/etc -DNATT=YES
> ```

When I try running this

```
[mpenning@Mudslide ike]$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DQTGUI=YES \
> -DETCDIR=/etc -DNATT=YES
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to 
"Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to 
select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may 
be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may 
be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module 
 file:/home/mpenning/src/ike/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may 
be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may 
be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module 
 file:/home/mpenning/src/ike/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[mpenning@Mudslide ike]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the resolution... I was missing:

- `g++`
- `make`

Those got me past the first error; however, several other dependencies came up after I fixed that.  Ultimately installing these made the compile successful...

- `flex`
- `bison`
- `libssl-dev`
- `libedit-dev`

After that, I disabled `Qt` dependencies (because I didn't want the bloat), and it configured without problems...

```
[mpenning@Mudslide ike]$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
>  -DQTGUI=NO -DETCDIR=/etc -DNATT=YES
-- Using install prefix /usr ...
-- Using etc install path /etc ...
-- Using bin install path /usr/bin ...
-- Using sbin install path /usr/sbin ...
-- Using lib install path /usr/lib ...
-- Using man install path /usr/local/man ...
-- Using library -lpthread
-- Using binary /usr/bin/flex ...
-- Using binary /usr/bin/bison ...
-- Enabled NAT Traversal support ...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mpenning/src/ike
[mpenning@Mudslide ike]$
```

After that, `make` and `sudo make install` compiled and installed correctly...

```
[mpenning@Mudslide ike]$ which ikec
/usr/bin/ikec
[mpenning@Mudslide ike]$ ikec -h
ii : ## : VPN Connect, ver 2.2.1
## : Copyright 2013 Shrew Soft Inc.
## : press the <h> key for help
!! : invalid parameters specified ...
>> : ikec -r "name" [ -u <user> ][ -p <pass> ][ -a ]
 -r     site configuration path
 -u     connection user name
 -p     connection user password
 -a     auto connect
[mpenning@Mudslide ike]$
```